# Docker toolbox got stuck with command

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I'm new to Docker, i'm using the Toolbox version for dockers. I try the following command:

```
docker run -it --name myflask1 -p 192.168.99.100:5000 -v ${PWD}:/app python:3.7 bash
```

The following message appear:

```
invalid publish opts format (should be name=value but got 'docker-machine')
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your `-p` option looks bad. Format should looks:

- `-p ip:hostPort:containerPort`,
- `-p ip::containerPort`,
- `-p hostPort:containerPort`,
- `-p containerPort`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i try the following: docker run -it --name myflask1 ip:192.168.99.100:5000 -v ${PWD}:/app python:3.7 bash, this also doesn't work